# How do I put a MySQL record field result inside a PHP Object?

Tags: php, mysql, object, record

I have a mailer script, and I want it to e-mail the person that filled out the form.  This info is being called from the database.  No matter how I try to format this, it doesn't work.

```
$mail=new PHPMailer;
    $mail->addAddress("email1@email.com");
    $mail->addCC("email2@email.come");
    $mail->addCC()->{$order_info['user_email']};
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject=$config["mail"]["subject"];
    $mail->Body=$message;
        if(!$mail->Send()){
            echo "Error sending Email. " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      } else {
            $URL="view-orders.php"; 
            header ("Location: $URL"); 
    };
```

I am talking about the 2nd addCC.  Is this not possible?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Saying that something "doesn't work", is almost always not enough information. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`$mail->addCC($order_info['user_email']);`

Or if you are returning objects,

`$mail->addCC($order_info->user_email);`

Comment: @SherwoodPro You should add the code that generates `$order_info` to your question.

Comment: That shows the e-mail is available.  The way I wrote it in my question is wrong then.  Your second option works.   Thanks!